# How to use KDE's desktop manager on Ubuntu/Unity?

Tags: ubuntu, kde, kubuntu, ubuntu-unity, desktop-environments

I don't know what program KDE uses to manage the desktop, but I love it, and I want it to replace Nautilus. Is it possible to get this program to manage the Ubuntu desktop? If not, can I use some alternative program that is similar?

I actually got Kubuntu's desktop environment installed on Ubuntu. I don't mean dual-booting - when I log in, I can choose my desktop environment, which include Kubuntu and Ubuntu. So I should have any neccecary packages installed.

I'm running Ubuntu 12.10.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Nautilus is a file manager, not a desktop manager. Kubuntu is Ubuntu with the KDE desktop manager. What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Nautilus manages the desktop icons in Ubuntu. I have seen an option to make Nautilus not manage the desktop anymore, so I assume I'm aloud to make other programs show the desktop icons. I found out that dolphin doesn't make the desktop icons show up in kde, so it's some other program, or it's built in. when I said desktop manager, I didn't mean kde, or gnome, I meant the program that makes desktop icons appear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a great article on how to use kde's plasma desktop on ubuntu. sorry if my question in unclear, but I meant something like [this](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2011/05/how-to-run-kde-plasma-widgets-in-ubuntu-unity).